# How to search a database with the name of a var

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have this code right here, and all it does is error a... 404???? (Just a glitch, but still. Using remote HTTP access it does not work. It should)

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO $user(Username, Password, Membership)
VALUES ($usn, $psw, $membership)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: A 404 comes from the server, not your PHP code (well, unless you're sending out headers, which you clearly aren't)

Comment: Yes, but it is a random error. But I still can't get this code to work on the 404 bypass (Http service)

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $user . "(Username, Password, Membership) VALUES (" . $usn . "," . $psw . "," . $membership. ")"
```

Comment: That's functionally identical to what's already there, though.

Comment: So you still say the problem might be the variables?

Comment: A 404 error is the webserver saying that the file isn't there. I don't think this is being caused by the PHP code, as apparently the webserver can't even find the file to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write either:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$user."(Username, Password, Membership)
VALUES 
('".$usn."', '".$psw."', '".$membership."')";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(Username, Password, Membership)
VALUES 
('".$usn."', '".$psw."', '".$membership."')";
```

Escaping your input and adding a real_escape_string() call would be even better.
So I would write it in a way that the values are escaped as strings and the query handles them as strings:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user(Username, Password, Membership)
    VALUES 
    ('".$conn->real_escape_string($usn)."', 
     '".$conn->real_escape_string($psw)."', 
     '".$conn->real_escape_string($membership)."'
    )";
```

I hope that helped at least a little.